# Display a text field on a node/add form

Tags: nodes, entities

I want to display a text field on a content type which is simply a paragraph of text (non-editable). Is it possible to add such a field.

The context: I have a node/add form available to anonymous users so that they can create a content type of 'contact form'.

I am using conditional fields to display certain fields based on the choices made in creating the contact form.

I would like to be able to add a 'message' that displays if they select a certain field.

For example: if the problem selected from a  select box is 'forgotten password' then the paragraph message would appear directing the user to the retrieve password page via a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [Static Field](http://drupal.org/project/static_field) module to add your text as a separate field. In this case it can be shown/hidden by conditional fields